# Using Openvpn (pivpn) can't check email

Tags: vpn

I connect to Openvpn (that runs on my raspberry pi 3, installed using pivpn script) using android phone. Everything works out of the box except my email client. I use BlueMail app and I have my email account on yahoo.com. App can't connect to yahoo server and thus check my emails.

I didn't have to provide email server settings manually since BlueMail has done all configuration automatically. On Yahoo webpage I checked that IMAP protocol is setup on port 993.

`sudo iptables -S`on my pi returns:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

`sudo iptables -L` on my pi returns:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any idea where should I look for resolution of this problem?

Comment: I do not understand what's your setup. You are using **openvpn** so you must have at least one VPN server and one VPN client. What is the RasPi, client or server? Where is the opposite? How and where is the android phone connected? Where is the gateway to the internet (yahoo.com)?